# Doxygen doesn't find m2cpp.pl

Tags: linux, matlab, documentation, doxygen, doxywizard

I'm try to use Doxygen for Matlab-Code with Doxywizard. For this I take a perl-filter from [MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25925-using-doxygen-with-matlab).
I set:

```
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.m=m2cpp.pl
```

The script put into the working directory. But Doxygen says:

```
sh: 1: m2cpp.pl: not found
```

I move the script around but the message still the same.

Where I have to put the script and how to setup the configuration right?

Comment: untested: put the script in directory, then add that directory to the `PATH` environment variable. Also make sure to mark the file as executable `chmod u+x m2cpp.pl`

Comment: also according to the [instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25925-using-doxygen-with-matlab), it seems you can specify the full path in the Doxyfile: `FILTER_PATTERN=*m=/path/to/m2cpp.pl`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem. The shell error you're getting is actually saying "Shell: `m2cpp.pl`, line 1: not found". In other words, the thing that is not being found is on line 1 of `m2cpp.pl`, not `m2cpp.pl` itself.

Assuming you have the version of `m2cpp.pl` that comes from [MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25925-using-doxygen-with-matlab) you'll probably find the first line is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl.exe
```

That is what is not being found, because the Perl executable is not called `perl.exe` on Linux.

Calling the script with the interpreter specified in `FILTER_PATTERNS` in your Doxyfile should fix it; i.e.

```
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.m="perl m2cpp.pl"
```

for wherever you have `m2cpp.pl`.

(You could also modify the script directly, provided you comply with the [licence agreement](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/view_license?file_info_id=33826).)